# Using Wp-query with serialized postmeta values

Tags: wordpress

I've stored some serialized data in wp-postmeta table, e.g.:

```
$data = array(
    'details'    => $dettagli,
    'vernice'    => $vernice,
    'reperibile' => $reperibile,
    'valore2'    => $valore2,
    'valuta2'    => $valuta2,
    'subcat'     => $subcat
);

add_post_meta($post_ID, 'meta', $data);
```

I would like to extract all the posts with the key "details" and value = "4". How can I do it?

I've tried doing this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => 
        array(
            'key' => 'details',
            'value' => '4',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    'meta_key' => 'meta',    
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
       $query->the_post();
       the_ID();
    }                          
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

`meta_query` is an array of arrays.
 You might try this:

```
$args = array(
  //parameters here
  'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'details',
           'value' => '4',
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
       )
   ),
   //remove meta_key => 'meta'
);
```

however i'm not 100% sure if this could help you, let's try it, please let me know if you get stuck.

**UPDATE**

Serialized array in post meta are not good deals. So i suggest you to change your save function to store custom fields individually.

I've found a way to unserialize your previous post meta values:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'collectable',
    'meta_key'       => 'meta',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
   //Get data for each post
   $data = get_post_meta( $post->id, 'meta', true );
   //Add post meta value individually for each field
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'details', $data['details'] );
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'vernice', $data['vernice'] );
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'reperibile', $data['reperibile'] );
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'valore2', $data['valore2'] );
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'valuta2', $data['valuta2'] );
   add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'subcat', $data['subcat'] );
   //Delete serialized data
   delete_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta', $data );

endwhile; endif;
```

Now you should be able to query as you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No results... This is the code I've used. Ciao!
$args = array('post_type' => 'collectable','posts_per_page' => -1,'meta_query' =>  array(
       array(
           'key' => 'details',
           'value' => '4',
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
       )
   ),
   
);
      
     $query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: @fabiodipa, serialized arrays in post meta are not good deals.

Comment: Yep, [not good deal](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Problem-WP-Query-with-custom-field-value-as-an-array-tp27401p27402.html).

Comment: I know... but theoretically should be possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this .Just a try

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'open', 'meta_value' => 'yes' ));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've tried with $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'details', 'meta_value' => '4' ));